# Creating a Word macro to type increasing numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, visual-basic

I'm a Youtuber, and I frequently create word documents that mark where I would like to insert images, videos, or sound bites, corresponding with certain words in the script, to illustrate the points I'm speaking about. I simply type, in bold, "[3]", "[99]", etc as my pieces of media are numbered by order of appearance. This can get quite tedious, as I often end up using 100, 200, 300+ pieces of media in each work. I also sometimes accidentally reuse a number when typing and then have to go back to change it and everything after it, which is frustrating.

Thus, I was curious to see if it would be possible for a Word macro to, upon pressing a button or hitting a key:

1. Enable bold text, for the text that will follow
2. Type "["
3. Type a number, increasing by 1 each time the macro is used
4. Type "]"
5. Enter a space.

I tried to make this code myself, with the following macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.TypeText Text:="[" & Right("000" & Trim(CStr(J + 1)), 2 & "]")
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
End Sub
```

However, I have no experience in Visual Basic and very little experience in coding, with my last major experience being HTML classes in middle-school and a bit of self-taught JavaScript, so essentially I don't know what I'm doing, and I didn't get very far.

Comment: Have you tried using a [numbered list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-bulleted-or-numbered-list-9ff81241-58a8-4d88-8d8c-acab3006a23e#:~:text=To%20start%20a%20numbered%20list,bullets%20or%20numbering%20switch%20off.)? I imagine you can create a keyboard shortcut to make the current paragraph a numbered list and then add the text/media/comment/etc. A numbered list keeps itself up to date, so if you add an item halfway you don't have to manually update the other items.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but is it possible that this is not a Word problem but a workflow problem? Would it be useful to you to first create the numbered list of media files and write the script around it?

Comment: @MDeBusk I can't do that, as I don't know what media I'll use until the script is done. The media directly corresponds to the words being said, so while I may be able to save 30-40 files ahead of time that I know will be shown off at some point, the rest have to be found after the writing/research is done.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I haven't tried that, but I imagine it might be more complicated. I'd be willing to try though, if I can figure it out.

Comment: Look at the answer and references on the SEQ field. Once you create such a field, you can make it an AutoText entry and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "fields" to generate SEQuential numbers.

Where-ever you want to start a new numbering Sequence, you should insert `{ SEQ MEDIA \rN }`, where `MEDIA` is a name (which you can choose) & `N` is the starting number, mostly 1.

Where-ever you want the next number in the SEQuence, you should insert `{ SEQ MEDIA }`

References:

- https://wordribbon.tips.net/T000089_Filling_Table_Cells_with_Sequential_Numbers.html
- https://smallbusiness.chron.com/increment-counter-word-46903.html
- https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be

Answer (score 0):

Coming back quite a bit later, I did try the recommendations but unfortunately none of these worked out. I ended up achieving my goal by using an iCUE macro to insert endnotes upon pressing a key, then automatically scroll back to where they were inserted (endnotes take you to the very end of the document when placed). I then modified Word's default document to make all endnotes a large enough font to see and changed them from Roman numerals to simple numbers.